# Instagram Basic Display API returns error for user with no birthday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, instagram, instagram-graph-api

We migrated the code from legacy api to basic display and after that we can't get any media for user with no age set in the profile. It always returns

```
{
  "error_type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 400,
  "error_message": "Cannot access app due to app restrictions"
}
```

After you grant access for the user with no birthday.

Comment: I came across this bug a while ago when i tried to obtain an access token for such user (users that are created now are required to input their age). both for instagram and facebook as the minimum age required is defaulted to at least 13 and users with no age are defaulted to age 0. I am interested on how you managed to get the access token for such user to begin with? From what I understood there is no known workaround exisiting.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that user has not specified their age and your app has a certain age restriction. Assuming that the user specifies their age and it passes your app's minimum threshold the error should go away.